# NetBeans - Need assistance in updating jProgressBar from autogenerated code

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, jprogressbar

(Ignore following sentence - I was being dumb). I have a feeling that I am calling the updates to my jProgressBar on the EDT (which I know is wrong).

```
@Action
public Task launchScenario() {

    return new LaunchScenarioTask(getApplication());
}

private class LaunchScenarioTask extends org.jdesktop.application.Task<Object, Void> {

    LaunchScenarioTask(org.jdesktop.application.Application app) {
        super(app);
        launchTestCaseButton.setEnabled(false);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        statusPanel.validate();
        statusPanel.repaint();
        totalTests = scenarioRepeat * selectedSSIDS.length;
        setProgress(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() {
        currentScenario = 1;

        progressBar.setMaximum(totalTests);
        progressBar.setMinimum(0);

        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) 500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        }

        int ssidsToTest = selectedSSIDS.length;

        //For every SSID, we iterate through and create an autoconnector object
        for (int counter = 0; counter < ssidsToTest; counter++) {

            try {
                setMessage("Preparing " + selectedSSIDS[counter] + " test case...");
                Thread.sleep((long) 2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            }

            setMessage("Launching ");
            AutoConnector ac = new AutoConnector(selectedSSIDS[counter]);

            for (int i = 0; i < scenarioRepeat; i++) {
                if (ac.connected()) {
                    setMessage("Running test " + currentScenario + "/" + totalTests);
                    currentScenario++;
                    passedTests++;
                } else {
                    currentScenario++;
                    failedTests++;
                }

                System.out.println("setting progress");
                setProgress((currentScenario / totalTests) * 100);
                progressBar.setString((currentScenario / totalTests) * 100 + "% complete");
            }

        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) 500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        }
        return null;  // return your result
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Object result) {
        launchTestCaseButton.setEnabled(true);
        setMessage("Complete. " + passedTests + " tests passed and "
                + failedTests + " tests failed.");
    }
}
```

I know for a fact (and feel a bit bad) that I'm calling the updates (`setProgress()` and `setMessage()` in the `doInBackground()` method, and I have a sneaking suspicious that I should not be.  <<

So the question is, where should I place the `setProgress()` snippets in the code? Would this require me creating a task with the `AutoConnector` class and seeing if I can update the jProgressBar from there?

I have used jProgressBars before, but not in this manner with NetBeans.

Comment: You state, `"I have a feeling that I am calling the updates to my jProgressBar on the EDT (which I know is wrong)."` -- and just the opposite is true. Almost all calls that change Swing component state should be made ***on*** the EDT.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the correction. More than happy to learn!


So since I can't call updates to the EDT in the method `doInBackground()` as stated by the autogenerated code, where should I place EDT updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is just the opposite of what you state at the beginning of your question. You state:

> I have a feeling that I am calling the updates to my jProgressBar on the EDT (which I know is wrong).

And just the opposite is true. All updates to the JProgressBar should be made ***on*** the EDT, and you're doing just the opposite. You should call no methods on your JProgressBar from within your SwingWorker's `doInBackground(...)` method.

Instead consider

- changing a listened to property such as your SwingWorker's progress property, and have the JProgressBar get updated in a PropertyChangeListener that listens for changes to this property, or
- Use SwingWorker's publish/process method pair allow you to transmit data from the SwingWorker to your GUI on the EDT.

Myself, I much prefer adding a PropertyChangeListener to my SwingWorker (on the EDT), and updating my JProgressBar from within this listener. I feel that it allows for better code separation with lower coupling and higher cohesion than the first option.

Comment: Ah yes. I actually wasn't thinking and I meant I was calling updates to the EDT in the working thread. Terribly sorry about any confusion.
I'll be doing some more research into the publish/process methods you suggested and report back. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I was able to get it to partially work! My progress bar is stuck in indeterminate mode, and before I enter the working thread, I call `progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);`. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @Andrew: debug your problem.

Comment: I figured it out - I was using setValue instead of setProgress. I have to figure out the done() or succeeded() method next, but I'm confident I'll be able to do it.

I also followed your advice and took a read on PropertyChangeListener. It's a bit out of my understanding, but I noticed that this is what Netbeans auto-generates. I have a much greater understanding of ProgressMonitors now!

Once again, thank you.